# What is the most scientific way of supplementing body with water during a two-hour gym workout?

Tags: workout, water, energy-drinks

*DURING A TWO-HOUR GYM WORKOUT*

- 1. **How often** does a professional bodybuilder drink water?
- 2. **How much water** is necessary **in total**?
- 3. Does he/she drink **in large gulps** or **in small sips**?
- 4. Is it a wonderful idea to **replace water** with some **fruit juice** or **milk**?

Comment: about 4) AFAIK some people use friut juice instead of expensive bcaa beacuse of (as they said to me) in theory bcaa would convert in glucose (or smth like that) anyway during workout session, so, better replace'em with the juice, cheaper glucose source

Comment: I believe you are overthinking it a lot. Have your water bottle with you, Drink between your sets an amount that feels right in regard to how thirsty you are. And about the fruit juice, I'm not convinced that's a great idea since all that sugar probably doesn't fit your macros

Comment: While I think there is some possibly good content in this question, having 4 questions in a single post makes it overly broad, and also opinion. (For example, bodybuilder A may prefer large gulps less often, while bodybuilder B likes to sip a lot). I also agree that you are way overthinking it. You should also specify what you mean by a 2 hour gym workout, there are myriad things you can do in a gym,.